# Mysql - How to Join Tables for Custom Field Headers and Data within 1 record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, select

`Products` Table:

```
id   product_name
-----------------
20   Toy Car
```

`Product_attr` Table:

```
id  product_id  label  value
-----------------------------
1   20          Price  20.00
2   20          Color  Red
```

Need sql statement to return one line containing values like so with headers.

```
id,  product_name,  price,  color
----------------------------------
20   Toy Car        20.00    Red
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  Products.id, 
  Products.product_name,
  Max(case label when 'Price' then product_attr.value else null end) as price,
  Max(case label when 'Color' then product_attr.value else null end) as color
FROM Products 
  LEFT JOIN product_attr 
    ON Products.is = product_attr.product_id
GROUP BY Post.headline, Post.date
```

However, I should write some considerations on your design:

- What happens if a product has more than one record d=for, say, color? (same applies to price)
- `LEFT JOIN` is to make sure products always come. But, can a product not have a color? or price?
- You are trying to have generic attributes, but you are losing the typing system, mixing strings and numbers (`value` field in `product_attr`). This is confusing and never ends up well...
- All in all: a product has a color? Declare a color field in `products`! A product has a price? Declare a price field in `products`!

Comment: Sorry Adrian.  I didn't clarify.  I just used this as a generic example.  My issue is the labels/values in product_attr can always be unique or change.  I will always be pulling only 1 row, but any attributes it has I would like to pull field_name => value.  I am using this for a excel export, might just need to use php to build an array and dump it that way.  Might just need to rethink the design as well :)